# How does naming work in python classes?

Tags: python, class

I am new at using classes in python. I don't get/ understand how they work. While I am familiar using functions, I have a sneaking feeling I am doing something really wrong with naming items in my class.

I haven't figured out an answer from any of the tutorials,
So of someone could explain this to me as simple as possible, and tell me what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appriciate it.

Here is my class - the goal fpr this simple class is to add 
1 to any number given to it, in this case that number is 5.

```
class do_math:

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.add = num

    def add(self,num):
        self.add = num + 1
        print (self.add)

x = do_math(5)

print (x.add)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: How do you want the class to work? Be able to call the `add` method multiple times, or just add 1 to the value passed in the class constructor and store the updated value in a class field?

Comment: @Prune: Please use a bit more care with your templates. This question contains an MCVE; what it needs is a better explanation of the questioner's confusion. Most of your template doesn't apply.

Comment: @user2357112: point taken.  This is not quite a MCVE: OP needs to show the actual output and expected output, and perhaps a few words on the confusion.  I can infer `6` from the final paragraph, but the actual problem(s) are not clear enough from the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have several conceptual problems here.  First, do you want `add` to be a value or a method?  You've used it as both, which causes the most recent use to delete the earlier one.  In short, you've destroyed your `add` function, which is the *first* reason your program doesn't work.

```
class do_math:

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.value = num

    def add(self,num):
        self.value = num + 1
        print ("self", self.value)

x = do_math(5)

print ("x", x.value)
```

Note that you have *not* called the method `add` -- not in your original code, and not in my simple update above.   Is this enough to let you unravel the remaining problems?  Another problem is that `add` expects a value `num` -- but what is this value?  The object already holds the `5`, and the `+1` is hard-coded into the routine ... so what else do you need, and where would it come from?

If not, then back up to an even simpler class.  Work through initialization and one-line additions; make sure you understand each step before you go to the next.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class DoMath:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def add(self, num):
        self.num = self.num + num
        print(self.num)

x = DoMath(5)
x.add(2)  # prints 7
x.add(3)  # prints 10
x.add(4)  # prints 14
```

The line `x = DoMath(5)` creates an instance of the class `DoMath`, and assigns it to the variable `x`. The number `5` is an argument to the constructor.

The constructor is defined as follows:

```
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
```

It has one parameter, `num`, whose value it assigns to an attribute/instance variable (`self.num`).

The line `x.add(2)` is a method invocation. It calls the method `add` on the instance of `DoMath`, with the argument `2`.

The method `add` is defined as follows:

```
    def add(self, num):
        self.num = self.num + num
        print(self.num)
```

It takes the argument and adds it to its instance variable and prints the result.